# Adding an already existing database to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an MVC 5 web application. I have deployed it to azure but I can't seem to add the database that I am using. I know you can create a database on azure and link it to your website but is there a way to add an existing database?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to migrate an existing SQL Server database to the Azure environment. See this [Migration guide from Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/).

I have used the "Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure Database wizard" before and it worked very well and easy. Have a look at [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-using-ssms-migration-wizard/).